# Extend dataframe with a new column that is depending on values that are stored in another (variable-linked) dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following sample data:

```
set.seed(8760)
ID <- c(rep(1:4, each = 6))
i <- paste(rep(LETTERS[1:6], times=4))
value <- sample(1:10000, 24)

input <- data.frame(k, i, value)

wf <- data.frame("ID"=unique(k), "WF"=sample(1:365, 4))
```

I just can't find an efficient way to extend my input dataframe with a column that comprises of wf-values corresponding to each rows ID. Would someone help on that one?

Thanks in advance,
BenR

Comment: `Error in data.frame(k, i, value) : object 'k' not found`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join data frames in R (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `merge`, assuming that `k` is `ID`

```
merge(input, wf, by='ID')
```

or use `match`

```
input$WF <- wf$WF[match(input$ID, wf$ID)]
```

#### data

```
input <- data.frame(ID, i, value)
set.seed(24)
wf <- data.frame(ID=unique(ID), WF=sample(1:365, 4))
```